# Flutter Custom Painter

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

hello I have created a widget that extends CustomPainter. The problem is when the paint method is called the Size parameter width and height fields are always 0,0 I am not sure how to fix this. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated. Here's the widget. Thank you!!

```
class Box extends CustomPainter {
  double _top = 0.0;
  double _left = 0.0;
  double _width = 0.0;
  double _height = 0.0;
  String _text;

  Box(this._top, this._left, this._width, this._height, this._text);

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
   canvas.drawRect(
      new Rect.fromLTWH(_left, _top, _width, _height),
      new Paint()
        ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
        ..strokeWidth = 2.0
        ..color = Colors.blue // new Color(0xFF0099FF),
  );
}

 @override
 bool shouldRepaint(Box oldDelegate) {
  return false;
 }
}
```

and using it as such:

```
new Positioned(
      left: 0.0,
      top: 0.0,
      child: new Container(
          child:new CustomPaint(
          painter: new Box(block.boundingBox.top.toDouble(), block.boundingBox.left.toDouble(),
              block.boundingBox.width.toDouble(), block.boundingBox.height.toDouble(),
              block.text)
      ))
  )
```

Thank you again for nay ideas you may have!

Comment: what is the block variable?

Comment: The block variable is just a class I am using to pass around coordinates

Comment: that class is passing 0 values for height and width , did you check that?

Comment: Yes at runtime they are not. In  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) { }; The size variable has a width of 0 and height of 0. That's what I trying to solve.

Comment: you could add more code to your question

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A bit more code would be helpful but I think I can give an adequate explanation with what you have done here.

I assume that your Positioned is in a stack, and that the stack has a size due to another element in the stack (or due to being placed in a widget that gives it a size). For example, if the stack is in a SizedBox, Container (with size specified), or similar, it will have a size. Whereas if it's in a Center, it sizes itself based on its children.

In the case where the stack is sized by its children, it determines how big it is based on the biggest of the *non-positioned* children i.e. those that aren't wrapped in a `Positioned` or that are wrapped in a `Positioned` but the positioned doesn't define any of left, right, top, right, width, or height.

So back to your problem - if we assume the stack has a size, then your widget is being placed at the top left. However, as written none of the widgets under your `Positioned` actually specify their own size - you haven't set the size for the Container or the CustomPaint.

So what you need to do is actually specify how big you want your CustomPaint to be. If you know a specific width/height, you can specify that in the Container or in the CustomPaint's size. If you don't but rather want it to stretch to the size of the stack, you could simply remove the Positioned widget, or define both left/right and/or top/bottom. Or you could do a combination of a specified height or width + offset from sizes of you want. The last thing is that the CustomPaint may still decide to size itself to zero even if the widget outside is the right size. If that's the case, you need to pass in a size (I'm moderately sure that if you pass in `Size.infinite` it will expand to fill its parent).

The last thing is that I'm not sure what you're doing with your CustomPainter, but it seems like it could be wrong. If all you're doing is trying to paint a square, use the size that's passed into the painter rather than parameters (I'm guessing you're trying to do this to get around the issue you're seeing with size being zero though).

For example, if you're trying to simply draw a rectangle filling the entire painting area, use this:

```
canvas.drawRect(Offset.zero & size, Paint().....);
```

If you pass things in however, you need to make sure you're not drawing outside the bounds of the custom painter. From the CustomPaint docs:

> The painters are expected to paint within a rectangle starting at the
>   origin and encompassing a region of the given size. (If the painters
>   paint outside those bounds, there might be insufficient memory
>   allocated to rasterize the painting commands and the resulting
>   behavior is undefined.)

Comment: Wow! Thank you for such a well thought out and in-depth response. This has really helped me understand flutter and it draws widgets even more. Before reading this I wrapped the Box widget in a Column and Row with the CrossAxisAlignment set to Stretch which gave the painter a Size.

Thank you again for the excellent response. I really appreciate it and your passion!

Comment: You're welcome =). Flutter really is quite powerful, but that brings with it a little bit of complexity - most of the time it works pretty logically but you have to know a bit about it to see the logic

Comment: Agreed. I love it!!. Wish the IntelliJ ide allowed us to collapse widget trees as you can functions and html elements in a lot of editors

Comment: @user1026498 What if I know the width (fit to parent), but height is dependent on content? Like a card view.

Answer (score 0):

The default size of `CustomPaint` widget is `Size.zero`. To give a size of your liking use:

```
CustomPaint(
size: Size(100,100),
painter: MyPainter(),
),
```

To give your canvas width and height according to your device, you can use

```
double deviceWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
double deviceHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
```

Initialize deviceWidth and deviceHeight in your build method and pass it to size property of `CustomPaint` widget.

```
CustomPaint(
size: Size(deviceWidth,deviceHeight),
painter: MyPainter(),
),
```